# Akka Ask Pattern on future recover

Tags: akka, spray

I'm writing a Spray + Akka small server. And a blog post stood out and recommended this ask pattern. The `CapserOk` class has a signiture of this:

`case class CasperOk(company: Option[Company.Company], existOrNot: Boolean)`

I'm retrieving this database row and if it doesn't exist or some error occured, I want to send out a response from Spray to tell the client.

However, using this pattern, I don't know where to inject the switch.

I tried to change the code to this:

```
   val response = (secCompanyActor ? jObjectFromCasper(company))
                .mapTo[CasperOk]
                .map(result => result.succeedOrNot match {
                  case true => (OK, "transaction successful")
                  case false => (Conflict, "FileLoc format is wrong or it already exists")
                })
                .recover{case _ => (InternalServerError, "error occured! We will fix this")}

    complete(response)
```

Spray uses `complete()` to send out a HTTP response. `complete()` can either take two objects, or a string/serializable object. I want to use the two object mode (which allows me to manually encode its header), and an ideal situation should look like `complete(response._1, response._2)`

Is there any way to achieve this with Akka's Future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this via registering a call to complete function on future onComplete method.

```
response.onComplete {
  case (statusCode, message) => complete(statusCode, message)
}
```